# Laravel kreait package unable to create the messaging service without a project ID

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I would like to use Firebase cloud messaging, so I installed [kreait laravel firebase package](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase)
I created a service account in firebase console, included the downloaded .json file in my root folder in laravel and used

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=app-XXXXX-firebase-adminsdk-XXXX-XXXXXXX.json
```

in .env

---

Also created a controller for sending a push notification to a device

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;

class PushNotifactionController extends Controller
{
    public function sendPush(){
        $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');
        $deviceTokens = Auth::user()->deviceTokens()->pluck('device_token')->toArray();

        $message = CloudMessage::new();
        $message->withNotification(Notification::create('Title', 'Body'));

        $sendReport = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $deviceTokens);
        
        return response()->json([
            'Successful' => $sendReport->successes()->count(),
            'Failed' => $sendReport->failures()->count()
        ]);
    }
}
```

If I launch my Flutter app, firebase package creates a device token which i store in my database.
But if I would like to trigger the `sendPush()` with postman i got this error:

```
"message": "Unable to create the messaging service without a project ID",
"exception": "Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\RuntimeException",
```

From the firebase console I was able to send a notification to my phone.

The package should autodiscover the service account and project ID.
Help very appreciated!

Comment: Is the Service Account JSON File in the root directory of your project and can you make sure that it contains a `project_id` field? Please also make sure that zoo are on the latest version of the Laravel package and the underlying SDK. You can disable the auto discovery after publishing the package configuration to make sure that the JSON file is actually used. If these suggestions don’t help resolving the problem, please open a new issue at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues

Answer (score 2):

After some trying i find this command

> php artisan optimize:clear

The problem was that in the file "Factory.php" of Kreait library the function that search for firebase .json file use command

> Util::getenv('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')

At first I unlock this file for writing and check if the command "env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')" work, and it doesn't work, after the command that i write up all work perfectly.